# use actionscript to convert favicon to png?

Tags: actionscript-3, favicon

Using actionscript 3, how can I convert the favicon of a website to a 16x16 .png file?

this solution **must specifically NOT access online services** such as http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to bring in the ico file (assuming your favicons are ico files) as BitmapData.  Then format the bitmap data as a PNG file.  Here are some links I found to do just that.  Alternatively, you could build your own solution but that would certainly be the long way round.

Importing ico files as bitmaps:

http://ntt.cc/2008/10/02/using-icodecoder-class-to-read-ico-file-and-display-it-as-bitmap-in-actionscript.html

Generating a PNG file from bitmap data:

http://www.kaourantin.net/2005/10/png-encoder-in-as3.html

Comment: vikinghippy, thanks, I was aware of the icodecoder class - I actually tried it already and it is too buggy for my use. I appreciate the part about generating png from bitmap.

Comment: Well if you feel comfortable working directly with the file header to get to the image data, here is the file format for ico: [http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-ico](http://www.daubnet.com/en/file-format-ico).  If you do go down this route, please let me know if you need any help.